# TestRestTemplate returns 302 and null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My `TestRestTemplate` has been broken. I've been making several changes for the past few days and now the tests aren't running.

Specifically, when I run a test it always returns `302 FOUND` and `null` as response body.

Now, I'll list things I did that are probably the cause:

- I've implemented JWT authentication
- I've set HTTPS protocol

I use self-signed certificate, thus I needed to configure my Apache `HttpClient` (which I use to make calls in production code and it works just fine). Here's the `HttpClientConfig.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class HttpClientConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpClientConfig.class);

    // Determines the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
    private static final int CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 30000;

    // The timeout when requesting a connection from the connection manager.
    private static final int REQUEST_TIMEOUT = 30000;

    // The timeout for waiting for data
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 60000;

    private static final int MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS = 50;

    private static final int DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_MILLIS = 20 * 1000;

    private static final int CLOSE_IDLE_CONNECTION_WAIT_TIME_SECS = 30;

    @Bean
    public PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingHttpClientConnectionManager() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        try {
            builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Pooling Connection Manager Initialization failure: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = null;
        try {
            socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());
        }
        catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Pooling Connection Manager Initialization failure: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                .<ConnectionSocketFactory>create().register("https", socketFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();

        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager poolingConnectionManager =
                new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry());
        poolingConnectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTIONS);
        poolingConnectionManager.setDefaultConnectionConfig(connectionConfig());

        return poolingConnectionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy connectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        return new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
            @Override
            public TimeValue getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
                BasicHeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator
                        (response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    HeaderElement headerElement = it.next();
                    String param = headerElement.getName();
                    String value = headerElement.getValue();

                    if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                        return TimeValue.of
                                (Long.parseLong(value) * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    }
                }
                return TimeValue.of(DEFAULT_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_MILLIS,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestConfig requestConfig() {
        return RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionConfig connectionConfig() {
        return ConnectionConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .setSocketTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CloseableHttpClient httpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        return HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig())
                .setConnectionManager(poolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
                .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(connectionKeepAliveStrategy())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        final TrustStrategy trustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, trustStrategy)
                .build();
        final SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
        final Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder
                .<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                .register("https", socketFactory)
                .register("http", new PlainConnectionSocketFactory())
                .build();
        return socketFactoryRegistry;
    }

    @Bean
    public Runnable idleConnectionMonitor(final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
            public void run() {
                try {
                    if (connectionManager != null) {
                        LOGGER.trace("run IdleConnectionMonitor - Closing expired and idle connections...");
                        connectionManager.closeExpired();
                        connectionManager.closeIdle(TimeValue.of(
                                CLOSE_IDLE_CONNECTION_WAIT_TIME_SECS, TimeUnit.SECONDS
                        ));
                    }
                    else {
                        LOGGER.trace("run IdleConnectionMonitor - Http Client Connection manager is not initialised");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("run IdleConnectionMonitor - Exception occurred. msg={}, e={}", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Previously, I've had `TestRestTemplate` just autowired, without any configuration. Now, after all the changes, it does not work. I thought that maybe the `HttpClientConfig` configuration bean may affect my `TestRestTemplate` so I've tried that:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault(); // <-- I just want a default client for my TestRestTemplate
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory =
          new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
clientHttpRequestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
builder.configure(restTemplate);
TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate(builder);
String endpoint = "http://localhost:" + serverPort + "/api/entity/1"; // <-- http://localhost:{local_server_port}/api/entity/1
System.out.println(testRestTemplate.getForObject(endpoint, String.class)); // <-- returns null and 302
```

Note that the endpoint `/api/entity/{id}` is available to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of frustrating hours, I've finally managed to get `TestRestTemplate` working again. I've noticed that in the headers I was receiving, along with the `302 FOUND` and `null` body response, that the `Location` header would always be redirected to `https` URI.

I've said that in tests I disabled the HTTPS protocol, however I forgot to disable a bean that I used in order to redirect HTTP calls to HTTPS. Here's the bean and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` that I used to stop redirecting to HTTPS:

```
    private final static String SECURITY_USER_CONSTRAINT = "CONFIDENTIAL";

    private final static String REDIRECT_PATTERN = "/*";

    private final static String CONNECTOR_PROTOCOL = "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol";

    private final static String CONNECTOR_SCHEME = "http";

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoPostProcessor")
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory servletWebServerFactory() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat =
                new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
                    @Override
                    protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                        SecurityConstraint constraint = new SecurityConstraint();
                        constraint.setUserConstraint(SECURITY_USER_CONSTRAINT);
                        SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
                        collection.addPattern(REDIRECT_PATTERN);
                        constraint.addCollection(collection);
                        context.addConstraint(constraint);
                    }
                };
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createHttpConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createHttpConnector() {
        Connector connector =
                new Connector(CONNECTOR_PROTOCOL);
        connector.setScheme(CONNECTOR_SCHEME);
        connector.setSecure(false);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8433);
        return connector;
    }
```

That more or less solved the issue, but I also needed to enable Http Basic Auth back again, as I did not want to get into JWT auth in tests using `TestRestTemplate`.